# How to count all the Weeks of a month (including if 1st is saturday and the 31st is monday, meaning that would be 6 weeks)

Tags: php, html, date

So im trying to count the number of weeks in a month including the posibility that the 1st is a sunday or saturday and the 31st is a monday, meaning there would be 6 weeks in that month.
So far i got this :

```html
<?php
  for ($Month = 1; $Month <= 12; $Month++) 
  {
    if ($rstFase->fields['StartMonth'] <= $Month) 
    {
?>
       <div class="mounthDate">
<?php
       $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1, $i);
       while (date('n', $timestamp) == $x) 
       {
?>
          <div class="week"></div>
<?php
          $timestamp = strtotime("+1 week", $timestamp);
       }
?>
       </div>
<?php
     } 
     else 
     {
?>
        <div class="mounthDate"></div>
<?php
     }
  }
```

So a count correctly the months that have 4 or 5 weeks but for example july 2017 has 6 and it counts 5.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on which day a week start, but it's not the point here :)
Is this doing what you need ?

```
<?php
function weeks($month, $year){
$firstday = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year)); 
$lastday = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year)); 
if ($firstday!=0) $count_weeks = 1 + ceil(($lastday-8+$firstday)/7);
else $count_weeks = 1 + ceil(($lastday-1)/7);
return $count_weeks;
}

echo weeks(1,2017)."<br/>"; /* 6 */
echo weeks(7,2017)."<br/>"; /* 6 */
?>
```

Comment: That works perfect, quite smart how you did it, I tried to do something like that but i must have had something wrong because i always got 0, Thanks fot the help!